# parse google translate v2 json with php json_decode()

Tags: php, json

I receive reply from Google Translate v2 as json which looks like this

`{ "data": { "translations": [ { "translatedText": "Wunderwaffe" } ]
 } }`

then I pass it to `json_decode()` function and obviously I get a JSON object.
But how do I get translatedText value?

I know it's a really newbie question, but that's what I am with JSON and `json_decode()`.

Thank you in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over `decodedValue->data->translations` or `decodedValue['data']['translations']` with `foreach()`. Or take the leap and just access `[0]` of it. And then look at the `translatedText` member or entry.

Comment: thank you! although that would only work if I set assoc flag to json_decode(), but in my case it doesn't really matter. Just out of curiosity, how is it possible to do the same thing without representing json as assoc_array?

Comment: I accounted for both in my answer (I used incorrect notation initially though).

Answer (score 0):

```
$word = addslashes($word);

$url = "http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=p&sl=en&tl=fr&hl=en&dt=bd&dt=md&dt=rm&dt=t&dt=at&dt=sw&q=$word";

// also can use curl       
$response = file_get_contents($url);


**$response = preg_replace('/,+/', ',', $response);
$response = preg_replace('/\[,/', '[', $response);**


$responseArray = json_decode($response);

echo "<xmp>";
var_dump($responseArray);
echo "</xmp>";
die;
```